# Random days in date or datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to random only days in date or Datetime within a range of days in sql server, t-sql.
For example if dates have days between 1to15 i want to randomise days creating a day number between 16 and 30. Example: 2017-7-10 to 2017-7-21(random day within 16to30). Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would urge you to read your question and ask yourself if you would have any idea what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Hi Sean, sorry if i wasnt clear. In a column containing date I want to random days only within a range of 1 to 15.

Comment: So you want a random number between 1 and 15 or between 16 & 30. Do you want the output to be the same other date parts and only randomize the day?

Comment: Great Sean Thank you. Yes the other date parts stay the same, only randomize the day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @dateA DATE = '2017-07-10'
DECLARE @dateB DATE

IF day(@dateA) < 16 --day number between 1 and 15
  SET @dateB = DATEFROMPARTS(year(@dateA), month(@dateA), FLOOR(RAND() * (30 - 16) + 16)) 
SELECT @dateA, @dateb
```

[DATEFROMPARTE SQL Server 2012+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql)

No version specific:

```
DECLARE @dateA DATE = '2017-07-10'
DECLARE @dateB DATE
DECLARE @day INT

IF day(@dateA) < 16 --day number between 1 and 15
BEGIN
  SET @day = day(@dateA)
    SET @dateB = dateadd(day, - 1 * @day + FLOOR(RAND() * (30 - 16) + 16), @dateA)
END

SELECT @dateA, @dateb
```

New request:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET yourDateOrDatetimeColumn = dateadd(day, - 1 * day(yourDateOrDatetimeColumn) + FLOOR(RAND() * (30 - 16) + 16), yourDateOrDatetimeColumn)
WHERE day(yourDateOrDatetimeColumn) < 16
```

Comment: @i217 have you test this? I used variables for you to understand the process, but it could be fit in a single line. Do you need help with that?

Comment: Hi Horacoux. Thank you for your help. Yes the ideal would be to create a function and use it to update column containing dates or datetimes.

Comment: that is a whole new question! Let me see

Comment: @I217 no function is needed, see my edit. Replace your actual table and column names. In case of datetime, it maintains time part

Comment: hi Horaciux, It works, Thank you, How do I upvote and/or accept the answer?

Comment: @I217 See the grey triangles at the top left of my answer? click the one pointing up to give +1 upvote. Select the green check mark to accept it as a useful answer that solves your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RandomDate16To30DaysFromToday = DATEADD(DAY, FLOOR(RAND()*(30-16)+16), GETDATE())
```

Comment: (30-16)+16? You could just use 30. But I don't think this does quite what they want anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange it works ok, see multiplication before has priority. He could write 14 +16 but then 14 is a magic number coming from nowhere

Comment: @Horaciux ahh yes. But as I understand this question that won't quite work because if you get a high random number of a high day number it will become a low date number in the next month. Maybe that is what the OP wants but I don't think so.

Comment: @SeanLange that is right, I just so it. I used a different approach, not adding to day.

Comment: If days between 1 and 15 then replace day with random number between 16 and 30 and viceversa, sql 2012. Thank you all :-)